# SlickGrid Media Query Min-Width Issue

Tags: html, menu, navbar, media, slickgrid

it's time for another strange issue I came along, HTML+Javascript expertise needed!
Let's take a look at my problem: I am using the following template with the navbar menu to the left:
https://www.templatemonster.com/de/demo/58708.html (Demo)
If you minimize your browser window (while the menu is still opened) and your window size goes beyond 901 pixel, the menu bar is collapsing automatically. I looked into the template files, there's a media query used on it. 
Now to my problem: I am using a SlickGrid grid on the right side, along with a window resize event that gets fired,  but:
On the timeline the following happens:

1. Window minimize by click
2. Window resize event is fired
3. Resize Grid is called
4. Grid resizes
5. Menu collapses
6. Grid is not sized properly

My problem is, that I have no idea how to get any event on the menu's collapse, I tried to work with bs.collapse, etc. but without any success. Is there anything I can do with the SlickGrid style to avoid the grid from getting sized improperly?

You now understand that some expertise is needed here? 
Thanks a lot in advance, I am stuck, indeed.

Comment: This is a tricky one. Not sure that SlickGrid is best suited for display tasks in this kind of complex page. The only thing I can think of is to either fix the size of the slickgrid container element, or to put a timeout delay on a grid resize using the ```window.onresize``` event. It's probably not possible to hook into DOM changes bought about solely by CSS, although I haven't really looked at ```onresize``` much.

Comment: I went with the timeout delay you suggested, great hint, thanks!